# In ejabberd source, there is a function called jlib:nameprep, what this function done?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

In ejabberd source, there is a function called jlib:nameprep, what this function done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function accepts a string (JID domain identifier part) as an input, and returns either a string representing Unicode-canonicalized version of it, or an `error` atom.